# How to define which columns in a Spatialite database are the latitude and longitude?

Tags: spatialite, csv

I have imported a CSV containing points with coordinates specified in columns named Latitude and Longitude. How do tell spatialite that these columns are the coordinates of of my points?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add first a geometry column into your table with SQL

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('your_table','geometry',4326,'POINT',2);
```

Then populate the new geometry column by constructing point geometries from your Latitude and Longitude fields with SQL

```
UPDATE your_table SET geometry = GeomFromText('POINT('||"Longitude"||' '||"Latitude"||')',4326);
```

Comment: I would never guess this one!

Comment: It is the same in PostGIS (which do have also other  alternatives which are easier to write) http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_pointfromtext_linefromtext_etc.snippet and the same idea works also with Oracle Spatial so keep it in your mind.

Comment: adding a column with a select statement is a bit counter-intuitive, that's all.