# Load CSV in SQLite and then create layer in Tilemill

Tags: csv, tilemill

I have a big CSV file with addresses and their lon/lat. I am not able to load that in Tilemill directly. I thought to load that CSV in SQLite Db and then create a layer with SQLite DB.
I am not able to progress on that. I could not find a tutorial where I can load the lon/lat to SQLite and create a layer. I am getting an error saying no column as 'geometry_field' type. I think, it need some SRS value to get that worked. Can someone please tell what is the issue and where to look?

Comment: Load CSV for example with spatialite-gui, add geometry column and populate it with SQL https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104068/how-to-define-which-columns-in-a-spatialite-database-are-the-latitude-and-longit.

Comment: @user30184 can you please answer this question so that I can chose as correct answer?